# How many GREEN coats?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, lateral-thinking, alphametic

Yesterday at our local highschool there were

- 29 pupils wearing BLACK coats
- 27 wearing RED coats,
- and 40 wearing BLUE coats.

How many pupils were wearing GREEN coats?

Comment: If 0 isn't the answer, I'll be flagging this as too broad, because there are technically infinite answers to this.

Comment: I have now restructured the question, put the colour names into capitals, and made clear the solution relies on a connection between numbers and colours. Is that enough for getting the puzzle reopened?

Comment: Without the verbal-arithmetic tag, the question is too broad. With it, it's trivial. -1 from me, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aah, such an old chestnut...

> Just use the numbering A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4, E=5, ..., G=7, ..., N=14,..., R=18, ..., Z=26
>  Then BLACK=29, RED=27, BLUE=40,
>  and there were **49 pupils** with GREEN coats

Comment: Nice work! I think this answer is probably correct if 0 isn't correct.

Comment: The answer surely is correct. I had seen this puzzle before, perhaps with different colors, and of course I do remember the trick. It might actually be taken from the famous lateral thinking book by Edward de Bono.

Answer (score 1):

There were 0 wearing green coats, you mentioned everybody's coat color already!

All the other color coats were there to serve as red herrings and to show everybody's coat had been mentioned.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how the other people are coming up with their answers, only this seems logical. The other answers may work but given his information they're not necessarily right. Just a bad puzzle I think.

Comment: @CyanogenCX If this isn't right I'm voting to close as too broad.